# Unable to restart bluetooth service

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth

I'm unable to restart bluetoothd. I tried:

- `sudo service restart bluetooth`
- `sudo service stop bluetooth`
- `systemctl stop bluetooth`
- `sudo kill -9 <bluetoothd-pid>`

But `systemctl status bluetooth` still returning:

```
× bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Fri 2022-10-14 21:03:19 CEST; 20min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1728
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9238)
     Memory: 2.9M
        CPU: 217ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1728 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

okt 14 20:57:18 MCY580 systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service...
okt 14 20:58:48 MCY580 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
okt 14 20:58:48 MCY580 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Killing process 1728 (bluetoothd) with …GKILL.
okt 14 21:00:18 MCY580 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Processes still around after SIGKILL. I…oring.
okt 14 21:01:48 MCY580 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: State 'final-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
okt 14 21:01:48 MCY580 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Killing process 1728 (bluetoothd) with …GKILL.
okt 14 21:03:19 MCY580 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Processes still around after final SIGK… mode.
okt 14 21:03:19 MCY580 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
okt 14 21:03:19 MCY580 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Unit process 1728 (bluetoothd) remains …opped.
okt 14 21:03:19 MCY580 systemd[1]: Stopped Bluetooth service.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

In ps aux I still can see that `bletoothd` is running:

```
 ps aux | grep bluetoothd
root        1728  0.0  0.0  10624  5320 ?        Ds   19:09   0:00 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

In `dmesg` I can see:

```
[ 4944.030004] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0406 tx timeout
```

I tried `sudo strace -p1728`, but it freeze mi terminal, unable to turn it off:

```
~$ sudo strace -p1728
strace: Process 1728 attached
```

I'm using `ubnutu 22.04.1 LTS` recently upgraded from `18.04`. So far I solved this situation by restart but it is getting annoyng since mi bluetooth keyboard stop working when this happends and twice even whole laptop freezed and I had to do hard restart.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403454/ubuntu-22-04-bluetooth-does-not-work)